¿Cómo guardar valor de checkbox en una tabla pivote usando Filament v3.x?
Estoy usando Laravel 11, Filament v3.x e intento realizar un registro de usuarios en donde cada usuario puede tener acceso a una o muchas sucursales y una sucursal puede tener uno o muchos usuarios.
Este es mi form:
 public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make()
                ->schema([
                Wizard::make([
                    Wizard\Step::make('General')
                    ->columns(3)
                    ->icon('heroicon-m-user')
                    ->completedIcon('heroicon-m-hand-thumb-up')
                    ->schema([
                
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('usuario')
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(20),
                  
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('nombre')
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(255),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('apellido_paterno')
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(100),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('apellido_materno')
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(100),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                        ->email()
                        ->required()
                        ->maxLength(255),
                   
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('password')
                        ->required(fn (string $context) => $context === 'create')
                        ->dehydrateStateUsing(fn ($state) => Hash::make($state))
                        ->dehydrated(fn ($state) => filled($state))
                        ->password()
                        ->confirmed()
                        ->maxLength(255),
                    Forms\Components\TextInput::make('password_confirmation')
                        ->required(fn (string $context) => $context === 'create')
                        ->dehydrateStateUsing(fn ($state) => Hash::make($state))
                        ->dehydrated(fn ($state) => filled($state))
                        ->password()
                        ->maxLength(255)
                   
                    ]),
                    Wizard\Step::make('Empresas')
                    
                    ->icon('heroicon-m-building-office')
                    ->completedIcon('heroicon-m-hand-thumb-up')
                    ->schema(
                        self::getCheckboxListsPorTienda()
                    ),

                ])
                ])
            ]);
    }

Asi es como genero los checkbox:
private static function getCheckboxListsPorTienda()
    {
        $tiendas= Tiendas::with('sucursales')->get();
        $components = [];
    
        foreach ($tiendas as $tienda) {
            $components[] = Grid::make()
                ->schema([
                    CheckboxList::make("sucursales[{$tienda->id}]") 
                        ->label($tienda->tienda)
                        ->options($tienda->sucursales->pluck('sucursal', 'id'))
                        ->columns('2')
                        ->dehydrated(fn ($state) => $state ?? [])
                  ]);
        }
    
        return $components; 
    }

Esta es mi tabla pivote:
  Schema::create('users_sucursales', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
             $table->foreignId('sucursal_id')->constrained('sucursales')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });

De esta forma estan relacionados los modelos:
Modelo sucursal:
 public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'users_sucursales', 'user_id', 'sucursal_id');
    }

Modelo user:
  public function sucursales()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Sucursal::class, 'users_sucursales', 'user_id', 'sucursal_id');
    }

De igual manera en el modelo User tengo el metodo boot que de momento solo he realizado la funcion de actualizar de la siguiente manera
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            // 
        });

        static::updated(function ($model) {

            $data = request()->all();
            
            if (isset($data['components'])) {
                $components = $data['components'][0] ?? null;
    
                if ($components && isset($components['snapshot'])) {
                    $decodedData = json_decode($components['snapshot'], true);

               
    
                    // Recolectar sucursales seleccionadas
                    $sucursalData = []; // Para almacenar empresa_id y sucursal_id
    
                    foreach ($decodedData['data']['data'] as $item) {
                        foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                            if (str_starts_with($key, 'sucursales[')) {
                                
                                // Asegúrate de que value[0] contenga los IDs de las sucursales
                                if (!empty($value[0])) {
                                    foreach ($value[0] as $sucursalId) {
                                        $sucursalData[] = [
                                            'sucursal_id' => $sucursalId,
                                        ];
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // dd($sucursalData);
                    $model->sucursales()->detach();
                    $model->sucursales()->sync($sucursalData);



                }
            }
        });
    }

Esto funciona parcialmente, ya que al hacer cick en guardar cambios se actualizan los datos en la tabla pivote pero después de hacer clic dos o tres veces en el botón guardar cambios (el resto de la info si se actualiza a la primera), quisiera saber cual es mi error. Entiendo que los checkbox se generan como un componente de livewire entonces no se si el trato que le estoy dando sea el correcto. Espero me puedan ayudar por favor.

Por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro, encontré la solución y es simple, solo faltaba agregar el método ->reactive al CheckboxList, quedo de la siguiente manera:
            CheckboxList::make("sucursales[{$tienda->id}]") 
                ->label($tienda->tienda)
                ->options($tienda->sucursales->pluck('sucursal', 'id'))
                ->columns('2')
                ->dehydrated(fn ($state) => $state ?? [])
                ->reactive()
          

